# TTS voice data selection

Tags: android, android-studio

Hello Developers I am working on TTS android .I change the tts voice to male and female by launching phone 
settings ->language and input ->TTS output ->Install voice data. So I coded to launch the voice data activity.

```
setting.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          Intent  intent = new Intent();
          intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.google.android.tts","com.google.android.tts.local.voicepack.ui.VoiceDataInstallActivity"));
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

[Screenshot Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2aQC.png)

The above code launches the activity that includes all language data.

I want to directly launch the English_UK option.

I also used adb commands to view the activity name but it only shows the above screenshot activity name . Sorry for my bad English..

Comment: The link you have attached stated the answer for this particular question .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Text To Speech Male Voice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815245/android-text-to-speech-male-voice)

Answer (score 2):

Please use this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#TextToSpeech(android.content.Context,%20android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnInitListener,%20java.lang.String)) for your reference

```
private Context context;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

context=this; 
tts = new TextToSpeech(context, this, "com.google.android.tts"); }
```

**OR**

```
tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this, "com.google.android.tts");
```

Comment: how to code this whether i can select male or female voice ? . I set the TTS engine English.UK . It contains male and female voices. The above code not changing the male voice .