# Male Voice for Text-to-Speech Output in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, text-to-speech

I am using this Text-to-Speech Plugin: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/TextToSpeechPlugin (Xam.Plugins.TextToSpeech)

The Speech output here is only female, even if I tweak it, the output will sound awful

```
Female: await CrossTextToSpeech.Current.Speak(Text, speakRate: (float)0.9, pitch: (float)1.1f);

Tweaked(for male): await CrossTextToSpeech.Current.Speak(Text, speakRate: (float)0.9, pitch: (float)0.3f, volume: (float)1.5, crossLocale: null);
```

I don't know what values to tweak here to produce a male voice, except for the pitch and speak rate, did anyone already found a solution for this?

Comment: Nope, this plugin cannot be setted male voice, you can make a feature request in this plugin's github page.https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/TextToSpeechPlugin/issues

Comment: are there any text to speech plugins that have male and female voice? I have not found one so far...

Comment: I cannot found this pulgins in xamarin forms. But native Android TTS could set the male voice.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815245/android-text-to-speech-male-voice

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin.Essentials use the built-in voices on Android and the user can choose to use either male or female alternatives when both are available.

That said, Xamarin.Essentials do not to my knowledge as of today provide any support to choose between the voices, only the Locales (languages):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.essentials.locale?view=xamarin-essentials

I guess you can lower the pitch for a darker voice and raise it for a more high-pitched voice, but the basic voice is still male or female and might sound strange if you lower or raise the pitch too much.