# How to change voice used by Google TTS (Text-to-speech)

Tags: android, speech, google-text-to-speech

Is it possible to change the voice used by Android Text-to-speech? I know that my device has some good voices because when I go to Settings>Accessibility>Text-to-Speech output>Preferred engine (Google Text-to-speech)>Gear icon>Install voice data>English (UK) I get to a screen listing 7 different voices, I am able to listen to samples of all these voices, and all sound human (and I think "Voice I" is the voice used by Google Maps). However, I don't see any way of selecting any of them. Apps that use Text-to-speech sound like a robot. How do I actually select one of the more human voices for use by TTS?

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41609132/10695663) help?